# Firefox and IE are adding space in my navigation area on 3 of the 5 pages, but not all of them

Tags: css, padding

I am trying to figure out what is off with my site- There are 5 pages, all linked to the same css styling file, created in the same way. In Safari, Chrome, and Opera everything looks fine. In Firefox and IE the navigation has space added between the links on 3 of the 5 pages. About us and Gallery are fine, but Services, Projects, and Contact have an extra top or bottom padding displayed and I cannot find any differences in the code on these pages.

The site is: www.vipercabling.com

Any thoughts on this one would be of great value to me!

Thanks in advance for your time

AB

Comment: Please don't post links to existing web pages, they will be gone or modified in the future. If you want someone help you, distill the relevant code and post it in your question and in a http://jsfiddle.net. This way, you learn how to tackle such problems yourself, and help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

The vertical space in the navigation appears to change from page to page because of a CSS definition on the `<body>` tag, set in `demo.css`:

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans",helvetica,arial;
}
```

It seems that `demo.css` is included on some pages and not on others. The "About" page has it, while the "Services" page does not.

Disabling that `font-family` definition in FireBug makes the navigation look the same on the "About" and "Services" pages.